# Can't plug solution to system of equations into function

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, replacement

I'm defining a new function by plugging the solution to a system of equations into an existing function. I cannot calculate the value of the new function for given variable values. I'm providing a simplified example below.

First setting up my original functions:

```
fa[x1_, x2_] := 2 x1 + x2
fb[x1_, x2_] := x1 + 2 x2
f[x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_] := (x2 - y1) fa[x1, x2] + (x1 - y2) fb[x1, x2]
```

Now optimizing. I struggled using Mathematica's maximize/minimize commands (my actual problem is somewhat more complicated than this example), so I have Mathematica find the derivatives and set equal to zero:

```
dfdx1[x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_] := D[f[x1, x2, y1, y2], x1]
dfdx2[x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_] := D[f[x1, x2, y1, y2], x2]
sol := Solve[dfdx1[x1, x2, y1, y2] == 0 && dfdx2[x1, x2, y1, y2] == 0, {x1, x2}, Reals]
```

This correctly produces $x1=\frac{y2}{2}$ and $x2=\frac{y1}{2}$. Now I define my new function:

```
ga[y1_,y2_]:=fa[x1/.sol,x2/.sol]
```

This new function $ga(y1,y2)$ behaves as expected in some cases:
`Print[ga[y1,y2]]` outputs $\{\frac{y1}{2}+y2\}$ and `D[ga[y1,y2],y1]` returns $\{\frac{1}{2}\}$.

However, simply plugging in values for y1 and y2 does not work. For example, `ga[1,0]` returns $\{\frac{y1}{2}+y2\}$ instead of $\{\frac{1}{2}\}$.

How can I calculate values of ga for specific y1 and y2?

Comment: Define `ga` using `Set` (`=`) instead of `SetDelayed` (`:=`), since you really don't need its value to be recalculated every time the function is invoked, and it will work: `ga[y1_, y2_] = fa[x1 /. sol, x2 /. sol]; ga[1, 0]` returns `{1/2}`. You might want to read up on the differences between the two.

Comment: @MarcoB That works. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.